POST call failed: InvalidApiName: API name is invalid. AMPLIFY gen 2
I am trying to make a POST request to an HTTP API endpoint from my Next.js server-side function using AWS Amplify GEN 2, but I am getting the following error:
POST call failed:
InvalidApiName: API name is invalid.
Here is my code:
JavaScript
'use server';

import { fetchAuthSession } from 'aws-amplify/auth/server';
import { post } from 'aws-amplify/api/server';
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import outputs from './../../../../../../amplify_outputs.json';
import { createServerRunner } from '@aws-amplify/adapter-nextjs';
import { Amplify } from 'aws-amplify';

Amplify.configure(outputs, { ssr: true });

const { runWithAmplifyServerContext } = createServerRunner({
  config: outputs,
});

console.log('NEW CONFIG', JSON.stringify(outputs, null, 2));

export default async function createUser(formData: FormData) {
  const nameInput = formData.get('userName') as string;
  const emailInput = formData.get('email') as string;
  const companyIdInput = formData.get('companyId') as string;

  try {
    const responseData = await runWithAmplifyServerContext({
      nextServerContext: { cookies },
      operation: async (contextSpec: any) => {
        const session = await fetchAuthSession(contextSpec);
        const token = session.tokens?.idToken?.toString() as string;
        console.log('token', token);

        const bodyContent = JSON.stringify({
          companyId: companyIdInput,
          userName: nameInput,
          email: emailInput,
        });

        const { response } = await post(contextSpec, {
          apiName: "myHttp",
          path: '/cognito-create-user-path',
          options: {
            body: bodyContent,
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
          },
        });

        const responseBody = (await response).body;

        return responseBody;
      },
    });

    console.log('POST call succeeded');
    console.log(responseData);

    return {
      success: true,
      message: 'User created successfully',
      userData: responseData,
    };
  } catch (error: any) {
    console.error('POST call failed:', error);

    let errorMessage = 'An unexpected error occurred';
    if (error.response && error.response.json) {
      try {
        const errorBody = await error.response.json();
        errorMessage = errorBody.message || errorMessage;
      } catch {
        // Use default error message
      }
    } else if (error.message) {
      errorMessage = error.message;
    }

    return {
      success: false,
      message: errorMessage,
    };
  }
}



The server component has logged output containing custom API information:
{
  "custom": {
    "API": {
      "myHttpApi": {
        "endpoint": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "region": "eu-central-2",
        "apiName": "myHttp"
      }
    }
  }
}

Authorization settings: Authorization is set to:
Copy
cognito-create-user-path POST JWT Auth
Invocation: The function is invoked through the client-side component using Next.js Server Actions.
Client component structure:
jsx
Copy
'use client';

// ... (other imports and code)

const InviteEmployeeComponent = ({ companyId }) => {
  return (
    <div className="w-full max-w-sm p-6 bg-neutral-100 rounded-2xl shadow-lg">
      <h3 className="mb-4 text-xl font-semibold text-gray-800 text-center">
        Invite Team Member
      </h3>
      <form id="inviteForm" action={createUser}>
        {/* Hidden input for companyId */}
        <input type="hidden" name="companyId" value={companyId || ''} />
        {/* ... (other form fields) */}
      </form>
    </div>
  );`your text`
};

export default Invite......

your text
